# Node server with multiple methods/paths

Tags: node.js

How can i write multiple methods (paths) in node.
For example i will run a node server at localhost:8080.

Then my url will look like localhost:8080/getinfo, localhost:8080/contactus, etc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start using routes. Try something like this.

```
app.get('/methodName', function(req, res) {
  res.render('ViewFile.ejs');
});
```

Add this to your `server.js` file. Also, I would super suggest [express](http://expressjs.com/)!